# Reverse Tethering ubuntu to iphone

Tags: iphone, tethering, reverse-tethering

I want to share my ubuntu's internet connection to iphone 5.Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use your ubuntu computer to create a wireless hotspot.
This allows other devices to connect to you without a separate network, and allows you to share an internet connection you've made with another interface, such as to a wired network or over the cellular network.

Click the icon at the very right of the menu bar and select System Settings.

Open Network and select Wireless on the left.

Click the Use as Hotspot button.

If you are already connected to a wireless network, you will be asked if you want to disconnect from that network. A single wireless adapter can only connect to or create one network at a time. Click Create Hotspot to confirm.
 Refer this link:
https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-adhoc.html

Comment: Ok. I have added some more information.

Comment: I changed my vote :)

Comment: The question is not asking for a wireless solution.  He wants to share a **wired** internet connection.

Comment: @YanKingYin: He is not specially saying wired internet connection. Looks like he just wants to connect his iphone to Internet.